# If blocks aren't full, why can't I set a gas fee of 1-10 gwei? Who dictates that it needs to be 20-30 gwei when blocks aren't even full?

Tags: gas, gas-price, fees, eip-1559

If blocks aren't full, why can't I set a gas fee of 1-10 gwei? Who dictates that it needs to be 20-30 gwei when blocks aren't even full?

And where is the best place to adjust my gas fee if I don't mind waiting 3-6 hours for a transaction?

Comment: You can certainly set the gas fee for 1-10GWEI, depending on your idea.
No one stipulated that it needs 20-30Gwei, but the current average price!
If you don't mind, you can set it low, and many wallets can adjust gas charges.

Answer (score 1):

EIP 1559 is what you should search for. A short summary: the protocol targets blocks to be half-full. Depending on how full or empty a block is, the base fee can go up or down by 12.5%. The protocol does this: the code is in all the Ethereum clients. (EIP 1559 was launched 2 weeks ago, so far you might see a block that isn't full, but if you look at a few more past blocks, you will usually see a block that was full: whenever you see that, the base fee increased by 12.5%.)

You can set your gas fee to 1-10 gwei as you have always been able to do in whatever wallet you are using. There is no guarantee that your transaction will be mined in 3-6 hours, because there might always be transactions that pay higher than you and keep the base fee high.

With wallets that support EIP 1559, they make it easier for your transaction to be mined because specifying a small tip (aka max priority fee) of around 1 gwei, so far has gotten transactions mined in much less than 1 hour: you do pay the current market price, the base fee, plus your tip.

Comment: which wallets support EIP 1559?

Comment: They should all be supporting EIP 1559 soon. For example https://community.metamask.io/t/metamask-supports-eip-1559/7286